# How to override the class without specificity?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a 3 scss file which are the `base.css`, `layout.css` and `contents.css`. I declare them as the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="contents.css">
```

`base.css` is for the default styles of elements. I use the `layout` for the `header`, `footer`, and also the `wrapper` of the website. As for the `contents.css`, the name speak for itself. Yes it is all the contents of the website. Since I got it separately, I don't practically use specificity. Like for example:

*base.css*

```
input {
  padding: 12px 0 12px 0;
}
```

*layout.css*

```
layout-wrapper{
  /*some styles*/
}
```

*contents.css*

```
input {
  font-size:1.5em;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
}
```

Instead of overriding the `input` of `contents.css` the style of the `base.css` gets read first and then comes the `contents.css`. I wonder why it doesn't work for `input` because in other elements it was fine. I can achieve my goal if I put a specificity in my `input` element but it would look like this:

*contents.css*

```
 layout-wrapper{
          /*some styles*/

    input {
      font-size:1.5em;
      padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
    }
 }
```

This would defeat the purpose of separating the layout and the contents. So my question is how can I override the input style from contents without any specificity?

Answer (score 1):

even having separated files, specificity is the answer to your problems, other may say to use `!important` , but avoid that at any cost.

Comment: I don't want to use !important unless its really needed. Is there really no other way than specificity? If I add a specificity then my scss will be 5-6 level deeper. I don't want at any all cost to go that deeper. Its a trouble having 4-5 level deep because of the unordered lists.

Comment: then add a class to input, and in your content.css style the input using class which will be more specific, and it is still the answer I gave, - specificity - check a [specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

Comment: Well I know how to put a good specificity but my trouble is my code will be repeated if I do that. As much as possible I want my code to be reused.

Comment: using class in an element won't be bad practice/repeated ( this comes from the guy who barely uses classes), and unless you can shows a live demo, it is hard to help and say why the input it is no applying in the last CSS file

Comment: Oh thank you very much. It will be hard to recreate the problem since its a bit complex. But I kinda fixed it using `@extend` to the specific place my element is. That is just for temporary fix. I still need to think how to override the last css file from the first one. :)

Comment: @user3771102 if this helped solving your issue you may think marking the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

you should give the defaul diff class names or element name like make it default-input for the default css

Comment: Well I'm trying to be as general as possible to be able to re-use my codes. I have like 20 css files that I needed to compress in those 3 scss. So having more class is like having those 20 css in 1 scss. I don't think it is good.